# Exception OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, out-of-memory, objectoutputstream

I want to save a big object

```
 public void saveGenes() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        String file = "genes.obj";
        String start = String.format("%tr", new Date());
        System.out.println("Save "+file+"...... "+start+"\n");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new     BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)));
        Genes g = new Genes();
        g=this;
        oos.writeObject(g);
        oos.close();
        String end = String.format("%tr", new Date());
        System.out.println("Save Completed......" + end);
    }
```

But I have to try this error
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$HandleTable.growEntries(Unknown Source)

I tested with -Xmx4096M, but the error keeps coming

Comment: You know `Genes g = new Genes(); g = this; oos.writeObject(g)` is redundant right? Just write `oos.writeObject(this);`. (But that won't solve your problem)

Comment: try what @Alba says and maybe don't include the BufferedOutputStream if that's not enough.

Comment: If something is too big, you need to break it down. Try to break the objects into smaller pieces and then write it to file, appending to the end of the file.  Imagine it was a text file, instead of writing the whole file in one go, you might write line by line appending to the end of the file each time. There Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could try breaking up the data into smaller parts also you could try calling `System.gc()`, but in my experience, it does not do any thing. But if it is placed strategically, I've heard that it works.

I don't know any specific reason as to why this is happening.

Comment: `System.gc()` is a best efforts to reclaim memory and is generally pointless.  The JVM will have released memory before giving up with an `OutOfMemoryError`

Comment: @NickHolt if strategically placed, `System.gc()` does work, or so I've heard.

Comment: `System.gc()` is heavily dependent on way too much outside of the class - the JVM being used, the GC configuration, etc.  As such it's effectively impossible to use it 'strategically' and it's generally recognized that using `System.gc()` is an anti-pattern.